# Accuracy Classification Result of Multiclass SVM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, svm, model-evaluation

We recently trained our dataset which consists of 18 classes (basic and compound facial emotions). Each class has a minimum of 100 and a maximum of 300 images. The images are also grayscale and the size is 100x100. The kernel that we used is RBF and the value for C and Gamma are 10 and 0.001 respectively. The model achieved an accuracy of 31%. How are we going to increase the accuracy of our model? As of now, we cannot change our classifier and we cannot decrease the number of classes, because it is already stated in our documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give a qualified answer without the data, so I'll have to speculate:

$100 \times 100$ is a $10,000$-dimensional feature space (and that's if we're taking greyscale only). You have no more than $300 \cdot 18 = 5400$ vectors in that space, which is terribly few. Classification based on raw pixels values only is likely close to impossible. Again, it depends on your data: It might work if the images are highly standardised, like the handwritten letters in the MNIST dataset, but unlikely for natural photographs.

So, the first thing I'd do would be preprocessing: Ensuring that the faces in the images occupy the same positions, are of the same size, in the same dynamic range etc. Next, I'd identify (actually, train a segmentation algorithm to identify) relevant parts of the image---eyes, mouth, nose, cheek...---to use as the features. I'd try to radically reduce the dimensionality of these features, e.g. represent the mouth as a curve or two, defined by its/their starting and ending points and the curvature.

The final classifier (SVM) should work on these features, not on directly on the pixels.

Comment: I used the HOG and LBP algorithm to extract the features of the whole face. Should we also consider it when segmenting the other parts such as eyes, nose, and mouth?

Comment: is there a way where I can send you the dataset that I am using @Igor ? I just need your insights about it.

Comment: Reducing the feature space dimensionality is crucial. How many features did you get from HOG and LBP? Re: Data: I cannot provide consulting services on your data. Can you perhaps update your question to show an image or two from your dataset? Maybe two extreme examples?

Comment: We had a total of 3808 when we combined HOG and LBP @Igor